# Bake texture problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

As you can see in the image, after the bake was complete, some of the faces of my 3d object looks full in black, but you can see in the 3dview that faces have an texture on it. Any idea why this is happening?

[image: my_problem]
Im a new user of blender, so for sure im doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Are your normals reversed on the object?  Try selecting all (a and then a again) in edit mode, and then ctrl-n will recalculate your normals, hopefully resulting in the outside being out and hopefully fixing the texture issue.

Comment: @Gliderman you save my day mate, ty very much. Do you know the reason of that change?

Comment: Hopefully the answer I added explains this. Also, please do not add [solved] to the title of your question. Accepting an answer will allow stack exchange to correctly show that the question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, while modeling, you get normals that are inverted. This can happen especially when working with the boolean modifier and other functions, where Blender isn't sure that you want to have the normals recalculated.

By going into edit mode, selecting all your vertices with <kbd>a</kbd>, and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>, Blender attempts to make all of your normals point "outward" from what it thinks the inside of your model is. You can also go to through the menus: Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside.

[image: Also access through Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside]

I'm pretty sure that the texture will only appear on the "outside" of the mesh, which is why after you baked it, some parts where black and not rendering correctly.