# Trying to Bake Texture But it's Black

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-baking, baking

So first I'd like to say I'm still a complete wreck at Blender, I'm self taught, which a lot of people are; but I might be making a stupid mistake, though for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

For whatever reason, I cannot get my texture to bake properly, it's black after every baking attempt. It is rendering correctly, the nodes are set up right in that regard I'm assuming. I'm not sure if I have something checked that I'm over looking, though I went through my settings multiple times. I have a light source.

If anyone could maybe take a look at what I have going on and tell me what's wrong, I'd much appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. To upload .blend files, please use [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). One problem I see is that your normals are facing inwards. However, I can't tell whether that's all, as the textures you're using aren't packed in your .blend.

Comment: I will get it uploaded with the Blend-Exchange right away. I'm sorry, had to google how to pack my textures. Here it is correctly with everything and I'll amend my post. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5647" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5647/)

Comment: Fipping my normals worked, I feel like a freaking idiot. Thank you so much. x.x

Comment: You're not a freaking idiot, unless we all are. Practically one makes that mistake, be it when baking or rendering. And a mistake from which you learn something, is a good experience, wouldn't you say?

Comment: I do agree, thank you so very much for your help. You've been very kind an amazing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bake texture problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90103/bake-texture-problem)

Comment: You're most welcome. I just flagged your question as a duplicate of another one, which asks about the same problem and the accepted answer is about the normals being inverted. Duplicate questions are OK, but marking them as duplicate makes it easier to find the answer, so don't delete your question because of this.

Answer (score 0):

simple. your viewing in texture, not material
 at least i think so... im reinstalling blender on my laptop to check r now

Comment: Thank you so much, and I added the packed version of my blend too. Sorry about that. Still very new.